# How to group measures to display on a Power Bi Clustered chart?

Tags: powerbi, measures

I have several measures computed and I am placing them on the Line and Clustered column chart to display them side by side. The challenge I am having right now is i can not group them for displaying on the Chart. Please see the attached screenshot.

As you see all the measures are appearing one next to the other, total of 10. I want to separate them and show them as a group of two. Is this possible to do, may be by using other type of chart? I have to use the measures coz they contain computed values from the dataset imported.

If any one has an idea over this, please help. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Group them how? What are your two groups?

Comment: @Alexis basically I want to display the first two measures in a group, these measures are Net Amount Actual, Net Amount Budget. Both are computed measures coming from different tables. So i want to format it in a such way that it only shows these two under one group, so these two would be showing side by side, then the next two measures would be side by side in another group. Currently all 10 measures are displayed side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new table with one column containing all of the groups that you want. For example: `Gross`, `Net`, and `Total` and put that `Group` column on the clustered bar chart axis.

Create a measure for the first bar of each group and a measure for the second bar each group. For example:

```
Actual = SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE(Groups[Group]),
             "Net", [NetActual],
             "Gross", [GrossActual],
             "Total", [TotalActual])

Budget = SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE(Groups[Group]),
             "Net", [NetBudget],
             "Gross", [GrossBudget],
             "Total", [TotalBudget])
```

Now put the `Actual` and `Budget` measure on in the bar chart Value field and you should get something like this:

[image: Bar Chart]

Comment: That's a great suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: I have a date column though, which is used for filtering and contain relationships as well with refresh. So won't it create issue by putting this into a different table?

Comment: I don't see that being a problem. The new table isn't related to anything; it's just for grouping the measures.